# Java Filter can not find config- object

Tags: java, filter

I have the following ServletContextListener:

```
public class MyContextEventListener implements ServletContextListener {
...
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        if (servletContextEvent.getServletContext().getContextPath().contains(CONTEXT_PATH)) {
            final InputStream inputStream = servletContextEvent.getServletContext().getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("my.properties");
            properties.load(inputStream);
        }
        SSOAgentConfigs.initConfig(properties);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle exceptions
    }      
}
```

}

and it is referenced in web.xml like this:

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>com.my.domain.and.company.MyContextEventListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

and I also have a simple dummy- filter which looks like this:

```
public class WSO2SAMLSSOSessionBeanFilter extends SSOAgentFilter {

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    super.init(filterConfig);
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {  
    super.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse, filterChain); // here the Exception occures
}
```

I get the following Exception:

```
Stack Trace
org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.SSOAgentException: Cannot find 
org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.SSOAgentConfig set a request attribute. 
Unable to proceed further org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.SSOAgentFilter.doFilter(SSOAgentFilter.java:71)
```

So the **SSOAgentConfig**- object I have set in **MyContextEventListener** is not be found.
Does anyone know what I can do in order to **SSOAgentConfig** is found in Filter?

**[EDIT]**

Filter is also referenced in web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SSOFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.my.domain.and.company.WSO2SAMLSSOSessionBeanFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SSOFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Maybe there is a filter for your SSOAgentConfig or you need to create one ?

Comment: Yes, it is the (extends) SSOAgentFilter but it does not work.

Comment: So you also need to add this filter in your web.xml

Comment: It seems there is a problem in the configuration. Has the my.properties file the needed values?

Comment: Yes, property file is fine, and with **SSOAgentConfigs.initConfig(properties); final String consumerUrl = SSOAgentConfigs.getConsumerUrl();** I can read the values over keys. but the Object SSOAgentConfig is not be found and I dont know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception comes from the `SSOAgentFilter` file. [Here](https://github.com/wso2-attic/carbon-identity/blob/master/components/agents/org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/sso/agent/SSOAgentFilter.java) you can find the source. This is the relevant part:

```
SSOAgentConfig ssoAgentConfig = (SSOAgentConfig) request.
    getAttribute(SSOAgentConstants.CONFIG_BEAN_NAME);
if (ssoAgentConfig == null) {
    throw new SSOAgentException("Cannot find " + SSOAgentConstants.CONFIG_BEAN_NAME +
        " set a request attribute. Unable to proceed further");
}
```

So all you need to do is to set a request attribute for this constant:

```
public class WSO2SAMLSSOSessionBeanFilter extends SSOAgentFilter {

// ...

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO figure out the right config for the following line
        servletRequest.setAttribute(SSOAgentConstants.CONFIG_BEAN_NAME, "the right config...");
        super.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse, filterChain);
    }
}
```

#### Update

Probably this fix could help too:

```
public class WSO2SAMLSSOSessionBeanFilter extends CarbonSSOAgentFilter {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have found it, the key is **public static final String CONFIG_BEAN_NAME = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.SSOAgentConfig";**. Currently I try to set the attribute but I dont know how until now. I would be glad for help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can `import org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent SSOAgentConstants;`, then you can use `SSOAgentConstants.CONFIG_BEAN_NAME` in your code.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to obtain the original config. Maybe you can try to extend the [CarbonSSOAgentFilter](https://github.com/wso2-attic/carbon-identity/blob/7a421e21941ff48914115f772d01027766f556a5/components/agents/org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/sso/agent/CarbonSSOAgentFilter.java). That will generate a config bean in case it's missing.